# How to detect if a windows named pipe has been closed?

Tags: java, windows, named-pipes

I've got a third party program which puts data into a windows named pipe.

I access the pipe with

```
String pipename = "\\\\.\\pipe\\the_pipe";
RandomAccessFile pipe = new RandomAccessFile(pipename, "r");
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(pipe.getChannel()));
```

So sometimes someone gets the 'perfect' idea to close the third party program before my small data converting tool which of course closes the pipe. When that happens, my tool writes down the last message received million times into the resultfile and successfully fills every hdd up to the last byte within hours, because I am not able to check if the pipe has been closed.

Things I've tried:

```
// checking file descriptor and file channel
if(!(pipe.getFD().valid() && pipe.getChannel().isOpen())) {
  // quit
}
```

But both options do not trigger.

Is there a other way to access named pipes where such an information can be obtained?
Or do I have overlooked something?

Comment: `isOpen()` only tells you whether you haven't closed your end yet. `isValid()` only tells you whether the FD is still valid, which it is until you close your end.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out too! In the end I've really overlooked an exception handling, so it's an error from my side - not lacking knowledge. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When that happens, my tool writes down the last message received million times into the resultfile

Only if your tool ignores `EOFExceptions` and -1 return values from `read()`.

Comment: Very good point! I really "ignored" it, but by accident... because I've got some decisions in that catch block handling the reading of raw files, where I forgot to handle the EOFException when I am NOT reading files. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) to access the named pipe directly.  Yes, you can detect the pipe closure if you use JNA.

I have done so in a project called [NuProcess](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess) available on github.com.  Particularly, look at the [com.zaxxer.nuprocess.windows](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess/tree/master/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/nuprocess/windows) package.  Look at the `WindowsProcess.createPipes()` method for setting up pipes (the code creates both ends, you only need one).

On the read side, *NuProcess* is using Windows `IOCompletionPorts` for asynchronous I/O (in [`ProcessCompletions.java`](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess/blob/master/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/nuprocess/windows/ProcessCompletions.java)), which may be overkill for what you need (or not).  But once you get your feet wet setting up the pipes, you should be able to figure it out from there reading the Microsoft API docs.